# Tabulator.js download / print nested tables

Tags: jspdf, tabulator, jspdf-autotable

I have a table with questions and one or more answers per question. The table is formatted in a way, that each question is a row and the answers are displayed below via a rowFormatter and a subTable. When i download the table as pdf, the nested data is not exported. How can I export the nested data?

Datastructure (example):

```
{
        "questiontext": "text",
        "timestamp": "2022-07-25T20:19:41.933Z",
        "answers": [
            {
                "timestamp": "2022-07-25T20:19:41.933Z",
                "answer": "answertext",
                "picture":"pic1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "timestamp": "2022-07-26T20:19:41.933Z",
                "answer": "answertext",
                "picture":"pic2.jpg"
            },
            {
                "timestamp": "2022-07-27T20:19:41.933Z",
                "answer": "answertext",
                "picture":"pic3.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Code:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    height: "805px",
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [
        { title: "Time", field: "timestamp"},
        { title: "Question", field: "questiontext"},
    ],
    rowFormatter: function (row) {
        var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
        var tableEl = document.createElement("div");

        holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);
        row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);

        var subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
            height:"1px",
            layout:"fitColumns",
            data:row.getData().answers,
            columns:[
                {title:"Answers", field:"answer"},
            ],
            rowFormatter:function(row_inner){
                var element = row.getElement(),
                data = row_inner.getData(),
                width = element.offsetWidth,
                rowTable, cellContents;
                
                rowTable = document.createElement("table")
                rowTable.style.width = (width - 18) + "px";
        
                rowTabletr = document.createElement("tr");
        
                //add image on left of row
                cellContents = "<td><img src='/pictures/" + data.picture + "'></td>";
                //add row data on right hand side
                cellContents += "<td><div><strong>Timestamp:</strong> " + data.timestamp + "</div><div><strong>Answer:</strong> " + data.answer +"</div></td>"
        
                rowTabletr.innerHTML = cellContents;
                rowTable.appendChild(rowTabletr);
                //append newly formatted contents to the row
                element.append(rowTable);
            },
        })
    },
});
```

Table (example)

[image]

Export (example)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching to do the same thing.

According some posts in Github, subtable export is not managed by the Excel export module.

Regarding Export to Excel Provision for Nested Table
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2932

And it seems it is only possible with a custom downloader.

The library used for XLS download is SheetJS
http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/download#xlsx

According the SheetJS documentation it is possible to generate an Excel file from JSON : http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/download#json